# Implementation of a delay in sound in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm just learning ARM assembly, and I'm not sure if my code is correct.  This code is supposed to implement a delay in sound.

I have followed the instructions below, but I don't know if I have any errors in my code.

1. Initialize the buffer 'buf' (when you initialize, it that register will point to the 1st element of buffer)
2. Store a size of buffer in one register
3. You have to make sure you are storing input values at right place, so compare your index r0 and buffer register (lets say r1)
4. If index r0 is less that r1 then make it r1 (i.e. 1st element in array)
5. Add size of buffer with r1 (now r1 is last element of array)
6. Compare r0 and r1 again and now if r0 is greater than r1 then initialize it to 'buf'
7. After that load ADC value to r0 and then store it in DAC
8. As each sample is taking 2 memory cells make sure you increment index by 2 (STRH r0, [r1], #2)

```
.set AD0GDR,        0xE0034004

.set DACR,      0xE006C000

.set BUFLEN,10000

.bss

.balign 2

buf:.skip( 2 * BUFLEN);  //'buf' intialized

.data

.balign 2

.skip 2

.text

/**
* void delay_audio();
*/ 

.text

.balign 4

.global delay_audio

delay_audio:

LDR r2, =0xE0034004

LDR r3, =0xE006C000 


LDR r1,=buf  //Store size of buf in one register

CMP r0,r1  //Comapre Index ro and buf register 

LDRLT r0,[r1 , #0]  //if(r0<r1) then r1 is the first element in the array

LDRLT r0,[r1]   //add size of buf with r1, so r1 will become the last element

CMP r0,r1    //Compare again

LDRGT r0,=buf  //if(r0>r1)  then r1 will be initialized to buf


LDRH r0,[r2] //load from ADC to r0( r0 is index)

STRH r0,[r3] //Store the same half word in DAC

STRH r0,[r1],#2 //increment index by 2 

bx lr   // return

.end
```

Comment: Note any edit that changes the question you posted to show the code in a formatted form.  It helps to make the code more readable.

Comment: _"and I'm not sure if my code is correct"_. Well, have you tried running it? What happened?

Comment: The code compiles , but I'm not sure if I have some errors.

Comment: Maybe the delay is too "quick" and i can't hear it